# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar el valor de varias entradas de texto generadas por un loop, Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Con el código que voy a mostrar a continuación quiero poder ocupar los valores que se ingresen a las Entrys en cálculos posteriores.

```
     for i in range(x):
        var=StringVar()
        if i<=3:
            label=Label(root,text="Velocidad del Tramo Ida")
            label.grid(column=1,row=19+i+m,padx=20,sticky="w")
            entrada=Entry(root,textvariable=var)
            entrada.grid(column=2,row=19+i+m)            
            m=m+5
        elif i>3 and i<=7:
            label=Label(root,text="Velocidad del Tramo Ida")
            label.grid(column=3,row=19+i+m-24,padx=20,sticky="w")
            entrada=Entry(root,textvariable=var)
            entrada.grid(column=4,row=19+i+m-24)            
            m=m+5
        elif i>7:
            label=Label(root,text="Velocidad del Tramo Ida")
            label.grid(column=5,row=19+i+m-48,padx=20,sticky="w")
            entrada=Entry(root,textvariable=var)
            entrada.grid(column=6,row=19+i+m-48)            
            m=m+5
        entradas_velocidadida.append(var.get())
```